# How can I customize the render of JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I've created a JRadioButton subclass in which I override the paintComponent method like so:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(
        isSelected() ? 
           getCheckedImg() :
           getBasicImg()
    , 0, 0, this);
}
```

but it seems that once the button is drawn, that's the image it uses forever. The isSelected test doesn't seem to have any effect. Are the graphics cached or something by Java? How do I provide my custom JRadioButton with a selected and unselected image? Do I have to write a custom UI?

Comment: What if you add a listener and call repaint() on the button every time its selection is toggled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the API. There are methods like:

```
setIcon()
setSelectedIcon()
```

among others that you can use instead of doing custom painting.

Comment: This preserves the model's functionality, and it's easier!

Comment: I guess I don't understand your requirement. The point of these two methods is to replace the "radio button icon" with whatever you want. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org
) showing the problem.

Comment: It's my fault this got voted down. I clicked the wrong button on accident! This solution totally works. It was very easy to implement and I didn't have to go screwing around with UIs. Thanks!

Comment: Checkout Oracle's (if not Sun Microsystems') ancient yet still relevant [Swing API guide on JButtons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more examples!

Answer (score 3):

To preserve functionality, it's not hard to extend [`BasicRadioButtonUI`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicRadioButtonUI.html) and override the delegate's `paint()` method. You can install your new UI using [`setUI()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setUI%28javax.swing.plaf.ButtonUI%29).

Answer (score -3):

Even in Java swing, I generally override `paint` rather than `paintComponent` in order to customize the look. I believe the default `paint` will call `paintComponent`, but only if the component **must** be repainted.

Comment: -1, custom painting should be done in paintComponent() not paint(). Read the Swing tutorial section on Custom Painting: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html

Comment: Thanks, I've read it, and several times before. However, the base version of `paint` calls `paintComponent` along with other actions; when I don't need those actions (which is frequent), I have no issues with overriding `paint`. You're just putting "RTFM" in a pretty dress. I have RTFM, and then I RTFSourceCode, and then I made my own logical decision for my own projects.

Comment: That may be fine for you, but this advice goes against the way Swing was designed to be used and therefore you need to explain the consequences/benefits of using this approach.