# Change selected dot color of JRadioButtonMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, menuitem

I'm working on my personal Java chat client whose one feature is setting user's status (Available, Invisible, Busy). To make it user-friendly, I put those statuses into a `JMenu` with `JRadioButtonMenuItem`.

The problem is I want each status `RadioButton` to have its own radio-dot color (or dot-icon). For example:

- [Green-Dot] Available
- [Red-Dot]   Busy
- [Gray-Dot]  Invisible.

I thought of extending the `JRadioButtonMenuItem` with three different custom `RadioButtonMenuItem`, but couldn't understand how `JRadioButtonMenuItem` is painted.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

**Edit 1**
Thanks for your suggestions to use `Icon` together with `setIcon()` and `setSelectedIcon()` methods.
However since my question is about changing the radio-dot, could you also help me to hide the radio-dot from a `RadioButton`?

**Edit 2**
Here's the current screenshot of my app.
[image: MyIM menubar screenshot]
As you can see the dot before that `RadioButtonMenuItem` is somehow ridiculously nonsense. That's why I want to get rid of the dot, or change it to my custom icon :)

Comment: See also [*How can I customize the render of JRadioButton?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3322733/230513)

Answer (score 5):

The radio button's dot is rendered by the UI delegate for each Look & Feel. You can supply your own [`BasicRadioButtonUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicRadioButtonUI.html), but the effort is not trivial. As an alternative, implement the `Icon` interface, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) in `ColorIcon`.

Comment: I think what you meant is set the icon of `RadioButtonMenuItem` to some custom icon? I think this will set the icon next to the text of that RadioButton, not the dot itself.

Comment: Exactly, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3323666/230513); I also wanted to emphasize how easy it is to implement the interface.

Comment: Please refer to my updated screenshot. To me having the black-dot is really annoying :P

Comment: I'd make it a single `JMenuItem`; change both the icon and text when the corresponding state changes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the Icon property of Swing Components. Here is example which sets an icon to the JRadioButtonMenuItem. Whenever there is a change in status use seticon method to change the icon. Instead of colors use icons

Here's an Example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Anexampleofradiobuttonmenuitemsinaction.htm

Comment: Thank you :) Could you refer to my updated screenshot? The black-dot before `RadioButton` really bothers me somehow :)

Comment: try using JMenuItem instead of JRadioButtonMenuItem http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#JMenuItem(java.lang.String, javax.swing.Icon)

Comment: +1 I don't know an easier way than switching to `JMenuItem`, but you lose the visual feedback.

Comment: @LuanNguyen With regular JCheckBoxes and JRadioButtons, setting the icon/selected icon is the method for actually changing the check box/button. Not sure why it doesn't work for menu items, I guess they did not add that functionality. As Sunny/trashgod have suggested I think you will have to switch to regular JMenuItem. I think you should be able to subclass it and keep track of a selected state yourself, setting icons appropriately. Also as a side note, along with setIcon/setSelectedIcon there are also setDisabledIcon/setDisabledSelectedIcon if you are disabling them ever.

Answer (score 1):

My thought was, the behavior of the JRadioButtonMenuItem is fine, it's just its painting is a little goofy. But I don't want to have to extend it or override paint or any of those shenanigans. So I concluded, just steal its behavior and leave its painting behind.

You'll notice that `ButtonGroup` accepts `AbstractButton`s, so I like dungeon Hunter's solution: use regular `JMenuItem`s. I'd append to that, steal the `JToggleButton`'s `ButtonModel` and send in an `ItemListener` that will do the image swapping (as Ramesh John suggested).

```
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;

public class TestRadioCustomIcon {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestRadioCustomIcon().go();
    }

    private void go(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Foo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");

        JMenuItem i1 = makeFauxRadioMenuItem("Item 1");
        JMenuItem i2= makeFauxRadioMenuItem("Item 2");
        JMenuItem i3= makeFauxRadioMenuItem("Item 3");
        i1.setSelected(true);

        ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
        bg.add(i1);
        bg.add(i2);
        bg.add(i3);

        menu.add(i1);
        menu.add(i2);
        menu.add(i3);
        jmb.add(menu);
        frame.add(jmb);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ImageIcon selected = loadImage("C:\\path\\to\\image1.bmp");
    private ImageIcon deselected = loadImage("C:\\path\\to\\image2.bmp");
    private ItemListener il = new ItemListener(){
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            AbstractButton ab = (AbstractButton) e.getSource();
            switch(e.getStateChange()){
                case ItemEvent.SELECTED:
                    ab.setIcon(selected);
                    break;
                case ItemEvent.DESELECTED:
                    ab.setIcon(deselected);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private ImageIcon loadImage(String filePath){
        try{
            BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
            return new ImageIcon(bi);
        } catch (IOException e){
            //sad day
            return null;
        }
    }

    private JMenuItem makeFauxRadioMenuItem(String label){
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(label);
        //Make it think it's a RadioButton
        item.setModel(new JToggleButton.ToggleButtonModel());
        //When selection changes occur, swap icons
        item.addItemListener(il);
        //Assume deselected
        item.setIcon(deselected);
        return item;
    }
}
```

And this'll work for any old icon, not just changing the button's color.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new class to customize the `RadioButtonMenuItem` by extending `JRadioButtonMenuItem`.

Add inner class to update status Icon by implementing Icon inteface.  Override all the methods update the `paintIcon()` method with current status icon.

Call super class by passing status icon.

```
super(theMenuText, new StatusIcon(theStudyIcon, getUserStatus(UserId)));
```

Add listner to get the latest event to update the Icon using `setIcon()` method.