# change the color of radiobutton's CIRCLE background

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I'd like to ask about quite a trivial thing if you don't mind. Is there a method under JRadioButton class that allows changing of color of the background of the "circle" that is ticked in the radiobutton, not that of the radiobutton itself. i want it plain white, not the default lightblue gradient. thanks in advance sirs.

Comment: You'll need to extend `BasicRadioButtonUI`, as discussed in [Change selected dot color of `JRadioButtonMenuItem`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024840/change-selected-dot-color-of-jradiobuttonmenuitem)

Answer (score 0):

you can set your own Icon
maybe get that Icon from the java libs or from the web
then edit them with photoshop or whatever 
and set your Icon

```
jrb.setIcon("source");
jrb.setSelectedIcon("source");
jrb.setDisaybledIcon("source");
jrb.setRolloverIcon("source");
```